What makes people say $\pi^{{\pi}^{{\pi}^{\pi}}}$ is an integer?
I know that $\pi^{{\pi}^{{\pi}^{\pi}}}$ being an integer is just a theory, but where does the theory come from? What evidence is there that tells us it could be an integer?

What makes you think it is an integer?  I note this question which seems to argue that it isn't.

It isn't that people think it is, but that it is surprisingly difficult to prove 100% that it isn't. You would think this would be easy to do, but we simply don't have the mathematical tools to do it.

@MikeBattagliaI think you should post your comment as an answer.

It's not a "theory", just a possibility. There's no proof of it being an integer, and also no proof of it not being an integer. And it's too huge for us to calculate it with enough precision to see if it's an integer.

pi is just large enough that the result is about a 666 quintillion digit number, which means its just outside the border where it could be feasably calculated for a reasonable amount of money. The same number with e instead of pi has only about 1.6 million digits and its easy to check if it is an integer. Anyway, there is a simple proof if it is not an integer. (If it is an integer you wouldn't know how much precision you need to be sure).

I suspect what either you or the people you mentioned are referring to is this YouTube video by Stand-up Maths. Note that it only says that it's difficult to know for certain whether that number is an integer or not. I think if you asked mathematicians about this, a majority would say that it's probably not an integer (and probably not even rational) but that proving it one way or another would be very difficult.
